# Java NullPointerException While Working With Arrays

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make an RPG in Java, and I'm trying to make a random encounter system. I need to display the names of enemies into the eclipse console, and I know that the values are set because I printed the names before, but Java gives me a nullpointerexception.

```
public class Enemies {
static Enemies Slime = null;
static Enemies Rat = null;
static Enemies Goblin = null;
//static Enemies Slime, Rat, Goblin;/*, Bandits, Sand_Worm, Antlion, Sand_Golem;*/
static Enemies[] Enemies = {Slime, Rat, Goblin};/*, Bandits, Sand_Worm, Antlion,           Sand_Golem*};*/
static Enemies[] monsters = {null,null,null,null};
int Atk;
int Def;
int Spd;
int Sp_Atk;
int Sp_Def;
int Hp;
int MaxHp;
int MinHp;
double Hptrue;
int Mp;
int MaxMp;
int MinMp;
int Level;
int MinLevel;
int MaxLevel; 
double XP_Modifier;
int MaxXp;
int MaxAtk;
int MaxDef;
int MaxSpd;
int MaxSp_Atk;
int MaxSp_Def;
int MinAtk;
int MinDef;
int MinSpd;
int MinSp_Atk;
int MinSp_Def;
String Name;

static void setstats(){
    //slime
    Slime = new Enemies();
    Slime.Name = "Slime";
    Slime.MaxHp = 10;
    Slime.MaxMp = 0;
    Slime.MinHp = 5;
    Slime.MinMp = 0;
    Slime.MaxAtk = 2;
    Slime.MaxDef = 0;
    Slime.MaxSpd = 3;
    Slime.MaxSp_Atk = 1;
    Slime.MaxSp_Def = 5;
    Slime.MinAtk = 1;
    Slime.MinDef = 0;
    Slime.MinSpd = 1;
    Slime.MinSp_Atk = 0;
    Slime.MinSp_Def = 2;
    Slime.MinLevel = 1;
    Slime.MaxLevel = 3;
    Slime.MaxXp = 10;
    Slime.XP_Modifier = 0.3;

    //rat
    Rat = new Enemies();
    Rat.Name = "Rat";
    Rat.MaxHp = 15;
    Rat.MaxMp = 0;
    Rat.MinHp = 5;
    Rat.MinMp = 0;
    Rat.MaxAtk = 5;
    Rat.MinAtk = 2;
    Rat.MaxDef = 3;
    Rat.MinDef = 1;




    //goblin
    Goblin = new Enemies();
    Goblin.Name = "Goblin";
    Goblin.MaxHp = 25;
    Goblin.MaxMp = 5;
    Goblin.MinHp = 10;
    Goblin.MinMp = 0;
} 
}
```

This is my enemy class

```
static void Encounters(){
    encounter = (Math.random() * 100);
    System.out.println(encounter);
    if(encounter * Ph10.player.Lck < 40){
        Battle.battle();
    }

}
static void monster_creation(){
    Enemies.setstats();
    monster_amount =  (int) (Math.random() * 4);
    System.out.println(monster_amount);
    for (int i = 0; i < monster_amount; i++){
            Enemies.monsters [i]= Enemies.Enemies[ (int) (Math.random() * 2)];
            System.out.println(Enemies.monsters[i].Name);


    }
```

The relevant part of my randomization class.

```
if( Map_Movement.tilenum < 34 ){
    battlezone = 0;
    Randomization.monster_creation();
}
```

The relevant part of my battle class.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: What line is giving you the NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Java are *never* "references".

```
static Enemies Slime = null;
static Enemies Rat = null;
static Enemies Goblin = null;

// This evaluation of the variables (e.g. Slime) happens RIGHT NOW.
static Enemies[] Enemies = {Slime, Rat, Goblin};

// Such that it is equivalent to the following
// (Which cause an NPE on Enemies.monsters[i].Name in the loop)
static Enemies[] Enemies = {null, null, null};
```

Either create the enemy objects *before* creating the enemies array, e.g.

```
static Enemies createSlime (){
   Enemies slime = new Enemies();
   // ..
   return slime;
}

// i.e.
static Enemies Slime = createSlime();
static Enemies[] Enemies = {Slime, ..};
// or even
static Enemies[] Enemies = {createSlime(), ..};
```

Or only add the enemies to the array once they are created (using a List/ArrayList would be much better here), e.g.

```
static Enemies[] Enemies = new Enemies[3];

static void setstats(){
    //slime
    Enemies slime = new Enemies();
    Enemies[0] = slime;
    // ..
}
```

There are many more quibbles that can be fixed, but this should be enough to move onto the next issue - have fun!

Comment: `static void Enemies createSlime` would not compile

Answer (score 1):

declaration

```
static Enemies[] Enemies = new Enemies[3];
```

settats Method

```
static void setstats(){
//slime
Slime = new Enemies();
Slime.Name = "Slime";
Slime.MaxHp = 10;
Slime.MaxMp = 0;
Slime.MinHp = 5;
Slime.MinMp = 0;
Slime.MaxAtk = 2;
Slime.MaxDef = 0;
Slime.MaxSpd = 3;
Slime.MaxSp_Atk = 1;
Slime.MaxSp_Def = 5;
Slime.MinAtk = 1;
Slime.MinDef = 0;
Slime.MinSpd = 1;
Slime.MinSp_Atk = 0;
Slime.MinSp_Def = 2;
Slime.MinLevel = 1;
Slime.MaxLevel = 3;
Slime.MaxXp = 10;
Slime.XP_Modifier = 0.3;
Enemies[0] = Slime

//rat
Rat = new Enemies();
Rat.Name = "Rat";
Rat.MaxHp = 15;
Rat.MaxMp = 0;
Rat.MinHp = 5;
Rat.MinMp = 0;
Rat.MaxAtk = 5;
Rat.MinAtk = 2;
Rat.MaxDef = 3;
Rat.MinDef = 1;
Enemies[1] = Rat

//goblin
Goblin = new Enemies();
Goblin.Name = "Goblin";
Goblin.MaxHp = 25;
Goblin.MaxMp = 5;
Goblin.MinHp = 10;
Goblin.MinMp = 0;
Enemies[2] = Goblin
}
```

EDIT for Explanation -
All you really need to do is not put a null value into the array Enemies. So I changed the declaration of the array to not include the values since they were still Null at this point. The enemy is created in the setStats method, so this is where you should put it in the Array. Feel free to ask if you have any other questions

Comment: Make sure to explain/highlight relevant changes.

Comment: You should have suggested him better code instead of repeating the OP's errors, such as naming (`Enemies` --> `Enemy`), indentation, overall design etc.